# Styling category names in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am trying to style category names with different colours.

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php

foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {

if (is_category('5') ) {

echo '<a class="featured" href="' . get_category_link( $category->cat_ID  ) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>';}



 else {

   echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->cat_ID  ) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a> ';}

   }
   ?>
```

It is not returning errors, but it is not working either...
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the page I'm working on:

http://216.172.178.12/~saracimi/eng/

and the snippet of code is relative to the rectangular boxes at the center of the page.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is_category will return true when you are on that category archive. you need to check the category id so try:

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    if ($category->cat_ID == 5 ) {
        echo '<a class="featured" href="' . get_category_link( $category->cat_ID  ) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->cat_ID  ) . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</a> ';
    }
}
```